# Convert json in javascript structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

searching the internet I found the TreeView library, analyzing its functionality, I decided to use it, I get the data from the server with a format similar to the following in a json

```
{
"company_1": {
    "sub_company_1": [
        {
            "id_1": "id_1",
            "data_1": "data_1",
            "data_2": "data_2"
        }
    ]
},
"company_2": [
    {
        "id_1": "id_1",
        "data_1": "data_1",
        "data_2": "data_2"
    },
    {
        "id_1": "id_1",
        "data_1": "data_1",
        "data_2": "data_2"
    }
],
"company_3": {
    "sub_company_1": {
        "sub_group_1": [
            {
                "id_1": "id_1",
                "data_1": "data_1",
                "data_2": "data_2"
            }
        ]
    }
},
"company_4": {
    "0": {
        "id_1": "id_1",
        "data_1": "data_1",
        "data_2": "data_2"
    },
    "1": {
        "id_1": "id_1",
        "data_1": "data_1",
        "data_2": "data_2"
    },
    "sub_company_1": {
        "0": {
            "id_1": "id_1",
            "data_1": "data_1",
            "data_2": "data_2"
        },
        "sub_group_1": [
            {
                "id_1": "id_1",
                "data_1": "data_1",
                "data_2": "data_2"
            },
            {
                "id_1": "id_1",
                "data_1": "data_1",
                "data_2": "data_2"
            },
            {
                "id_1": "id_1",
                "data_1": "data_1",
                "data_2": "data_2"
            },
        ],
    },
    "sub_company_2": {
        "0": {
            "id_1": "id_1",
            "data_1": "data_1",
            "data_2": "data_2"
        },
        "sub_group_1": [
            {
                "id_1": "id_1",
                "data_1": "data_1",
                "data_2": "data_2"
            },
            {
                "id_1": "id_1",
                "data_1": "data_1",
                "data_2": "data_2"
            },
            {
                "id_1": "id_1",
                "data_1": "data_1",
                "data_2": "data_2"
            },
        ],
    }
}
```

}

I have made several attempts to reach a correct result, however I have not succeeded. Can someone guide me on how to perform this function? please thanks.

the structure I want to get to is the following

```
var treeObject = [
        {
            text:"company_1", 
            children:[ 
                {
                    text:"sub_company_1",
                    children:[
                        {text:"data_1 data_2", val: "id_1"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            text:"company_2", 
            children:[
                {text:"data_1 data_2", val: "id_1"},
                {text:"data_1 data_2", val: "id_1"}
            ]
        },
        {
            text:"company_3", 
            children:[ 
                {
                    text:"sub_company_1",
                    children:[
                        {
                            text:"sub_group_1",
                            children:[
                                {text:"data_1 data_2", val: "id_1"}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            text:"company_4", 
            children:[ 
                {text:"data_1 data_2", val: "id_1"},
                {text:"data_1 data_2", val: "id_1"},
                {
                    text:"sub_company_1",
                    children:[
                        {text:"data_1 data_2", val: "id_1"},
                        {
                            text:"sub_group_1",
                            children:[
                                {text:"data_1 data_2", val: "id_1"}
                                {text:"data_1 data_2", val: "id_1"}
                                {text:"data_1 data_2", val: "id_1"}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text:"sub_company_2",
                    children:[
                        {text:"data_1 data_2", val: "id_1"},
                        {
                            text:"sub_group_1",
                            children:[
                                {text:"data_1 data_2", val: "id_1"}
                                {text:"data_1 data_2", val: "id_1"}
                                {text:"data_1 data_2", val: "id_1"}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

Could someone guide me on how to perform this function

Comment: what have you tried so far? Where inparticular are you stuck? JSon is already JS (thats what the JS in JSON stand for), so your question is really how to convert from one object to another

Comment: Have you try `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Can you add more details of the issue you are facing like an error or the output you are getting currently?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JSON.parse()`

The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the resulting object before it is returned.